# SVG animation with JS -- issues with transform-origin and stroke-dashoffset

Tags: svg, snap.svg, gsap, velocity.js

I need to create speed gauge with SVG. As the speed changes, a needle is rotated to indicate the proper speed on the gauge, and an arc is drawn around the gauge's circumference following the tip of the needle.

I have attempted to use three different libraries ([VelocityJS](http://julian.com/research/velocity/), [SnapSVG](http://snapsvg.io/), and [GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap)) to solve issues with the needle's rotation, but I have not succeeded yet in finding an implementation that works.

My initial attempts were with **Velocity**. I got it working in all browsers except IE. In IE, all attempts to change `transform-origin` failed.

Then I tried both **SnapSVG** and **GSAP**, but two issues keep coming up:

1. The needle's rotation mostly works well, but occasionally it rotates in the wrong direction, under the gauge, no doubt following the shortest distance to the point.
2. In IE, `stroke-dashoffset` causes unpredictable results.

I have created a **[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvKrMa)** that shows the gauge's behaviour when driven by either of these three libraries.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Snap version works fine for me, but I'm guessing the problem as mentioned is stroke-dashoffset which I can't test in IE.

One possibility if stroke-dashoffset is not possible, is to rebuild the path string each time. Uses a bit more resources, but I think may be ok.

Otherwise you could try drawing a mask or clip the same size as the arc over it, and animate that, but it will use more resources as well.

Here is a Snap solution, rebuilding the arc path each time.

Amended code...

```
var arc = Snap.select('#gauge-arc');
var arcLength = arc.getTotalLength();
var arcString = arc.attr('d');
arc.attr({ d: ''})

Snap.animate(0,arcLength, function( val ) {
      var arcSubPath = Snap.path.getSubpath(arcString,0,val) ;
      arc.attr({ d: arcSubPath });
    }, 100, function() {
      Snap.animate(arcLength,0, function( val ) {
          var arcSubPath = Snap.path.getSubpath(arcString,0,val) ;
          arc.attr({ d: arcSubPath });
      },500);

    })
  },
```

[Example fiddle](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epdMvY) (note, the other buttons probably won't work as I've removed the stroke-dashoffset in the svg markup).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Still, I'm looking for a solution that allows me to animate `stroke-dashoffset`, as that is less expensive. In the end I paid for GSAP plugin that does the job.

Comment: No problem. If you are using stroke-dashoffset anyway, I can't think of any reason Snap wouldn't work though. I thought the problem was that you couldn't use that due to IE.

Comment: Snap would occasionally rotate the needle the wrong way or along a different axis, so I decided it's cross-browser support wasn't rigorous enough.

Comment: What was the plugin out of interest ? Just wondering if it was CSS, which I guess you could probably do with Snap, but maybe not as comprehensive as the plugin.

Comment: DrawSVGPlugin. Comes with Club GreenSock membership.